# align in landscape and portrait SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I  have a single label View on a green BackGround. That Look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqcjz.jpg)   in portrait mode. When I change to landscape mode it should appear like    [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05uKt.png). Right now I am Interchanging the width and Height. Is there any alternatives?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        // background(Color.green)
        
        return GeometryReader { proxy in
            if proxy.size.width < proxy.size.height {
                Group{
                    Color.green
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                        Label("", systemImage: "")
                            
                            .frame(width: 350, height: 800, alignment: .center)
                            
                            .border(Color.black)
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .padding(.leading,37)
                            .padding(.top,25)
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                Group{
                    Color.green
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
                        Label("", systemImage: "")
                            .frame(width: 800, height: 350, alignment: .center)
                            .border(Color.black)
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .padding(.top,37)
                            .padding(.leading,25)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    
    
}
```

Comment: It feels like you aren't truly understanding what SwiftUI is about. Why do you need a different layout between portrait and landscape? (My apps are actually doing this, but use UIKit instead and will continue to.)

Comment: I am Using an image With a logo in the Red Portion. But when change the orientation, to landscape image doest rotate. I am New to SwiftUI. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: SwiftUI is meant to eliminate such needs. For that reason I continue to use UIKit and the various `UIViewController` overrides to determine height versus width. There's both pros and cons to using SwiftUI, and I just wanted to point out this is one of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Environment.

```
@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
```

App video YouTube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzmw8uMNrtI)

**Code:**

```
struct LandscapeView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if sizeClass == .compact {
                ZStack{
                    Color.green
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    Label("", systemImage: "")
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.9, alignment: .center)
                        .border(Color.black)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            } else {
                ZStack{
                    Color.green
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    Label("", systemImage: "")
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.9, alignment: .center)
                        .border(Color.black)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```